# How to change draw order of already created widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

Working with kivy, I can't figure out how to change the draw order of widget that have already been created. This simple app draws two images on the screen and what I want it to do is swap the draw order on every mouse click (move them "totop"). I have been playing with InstructionGroup but it did not get me anywhere.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.img1 = Image(source="./images/img1.png", x=200, y=200)
        self.img2 = Image(source="./images/img2.png", x=200, y=200)

        self.add_widget(self.img1)
        self.add_widget(self.img2)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print 'here I want to swap which image is drawn on top'

class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        parent.add_widget(MainWidget())
        return parent    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove and readd the widget, and it will be drawn on top.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.children[0] is self.img2:
        self.remove_widget(self.img1)
        self.add_widget(self.img1)
    else:
        self.remove_widget(self.img2)
        self.add_widget(self.img2)
```

Also, you should look into [Layouts](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html) as they will be much easier to work with than manually positioning everything inside a `Widget`.

Comment: Thanks for the Layouts hint, Ryan. It's a perfect way to organize, in particular, if you have many floating/scatter widgets.